# How can I show/find downloaded image from xamarin.ios in iPhone?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

We have written a code to download images from uri using webclient in xamarin.ios. When we download an image it's not displayed in Gallery/Photo app, or in any other location of the iPhone. 
Here is my download code:

```
public void DownloadFiles()
    {
        try
        {

            var webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadDataCompleted += (s, e) => {
                var bytes = e.Result;
                string documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                string localFilename = "downloaded.png";
                string localPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFilename);

                Console.WriteLine("localPath:" + localPath);

                File.WriteAllBytes(localPath, bytes);

                // IMPORTANT: this is a background thread, so any interaction with
                // UI controls must be done via the MainThread
                InvokeOnMainThread(() => {

                   // imageView.Image = UIImage.FromFile(localPath);

                    UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView()
                  {
                      Title = "alert title",
                      Message = "Download successfully"
                  };
                    alert.AddButton("OK");
                    alert.AddButton("Cancel");
                    alert.Show();
                });
            };

            var url = new Uri("https://www.xamarin.com/content/images/pages/branding/assets/xamagon.png");
            webClient.DownloadDataAsync(url);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

how to find this path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have added these permission in info.plist to solve this problem. **"Privacy - Photo Library Additions Usage Description"** and **"Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description"**